# What should be in the sources.list for Kali Rolling Linux?

Tags: kali-linux, repository, synaptic, rolling-release

This is exact content from my `sources.list`:

```
# 
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2016.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20160830-11:29]/ kali-rolling contrib main non-free
#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2016.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20160830-11:29]/ kali-rolling contrib main non-free
```

I couldn't install the Synaptic package manager and was told to modify `sources.list`.

I googled a lot and added some repos into it and ran update and upgrade command only to see Kali crash... I had to recover it.

Please mention the exact content that should be there to ensure that Kali Linux works.

Answer (score 10):

The [Kali web site](https://kali.org/) has quite good documentation, including [the answer to your question](http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories):

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
# For source package access, uncomment the following line
# deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

If you choose to hard-code a specific mirror, you can replace `http.kali.org` above with the appropriate entry from [the mirror list](http://http.kali.org/README.mirrorlist).

You should also read their page on [Should I use Kali Linux?](http://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux), in particular

> The fact of the matter is, however, that Kali is a Linux distribution specifically geared towards professional penetration testers and security specialists, and given its unique nature, it is **NOT** a recommended distribution if you’re unfamiliar with Linux or are looking for a general-purpose Linux desktop distribution for development, web design, gaming, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm coming from the future, 2021 to be exact, I need to add one thing to the existing answer as this question is marked in another thread about WSL.

If you are on Windows 10 and running Kali as WSL or WSL2 machine the apt may not work properly in the beginning due to a blank line in the `/etc/apt/sources.list`, you need to remove the blank line from the beginning of the file to resolve the problem (apt giving you 404 errors).