# apt-get upgrade won't work on kali

Tags: apt, kali-linux

```
root@kamil:~# uname -a
Linux kamil 4.12.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.12.6-1kali6 (2017-08-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux 

root@kamil:~# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

root@kamil:~# sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

root@kamil:~# apt update
Ign:1 http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates InRelease
Err:2 http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates Release
  404  Not Found
Ign:3 http://http.kali.org /kali InRelease
Ign:4 http://http.kali.org /wheezy InRelease
Ign:6 http://http.kali.org/kali kali InRelease
Err:7 http://http.kali.org /kali Release
  404  Not Found
Err:8 http://http.kali.org /wheezy Release
  404  Not Found
Err:9 http://http.kali.org/kali kali Release
  404  Not Found
Get:5 http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/Linux/kali kali-dev InRelease [30.4 kB]
Err:5 http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/Linux/kali kali-dev InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org /kali Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org /wheezy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/Linux/kali kali-dev InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

root@kamil:~# apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

As you can see, I installed Kali on computer last year. When I ran `uname -r`, I saw that the version of Kali is old.

What can I do to upgrade?

Comment: what is the content of : `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @Kiwy the source file is empty.
@StephenKitt, i will post the content of `apt update` and and `apt upgrade` below

Comment: @StephenKitt the content of `# apt upgrade` and `# apt update` is posted in the question details

Comment: Here are two questions whose answers will help you fix your system: [Invalid signature for Kali Linux repositories : “The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/421821/86440), [What should be in the sources.list for linux kali rolling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/370587/86440).

Answer (score 1):

Before running `# apt upgrade`, You need to run `# apt update` in order to check for updates.
In case `# apt update` will not show any possible updates, please check /etc/apt/source.list (`# nano /etc/apt/sources.list`) and correct it.

Comment: the source file is empty

Comment: The content of `# apt upgrade` and `# apt update is posted in the question details`

Comment: I'm sorry for misleading, in my initial answer I made mistake: You need to check `/etc/apt/sources.list` (instead of /etc/apt source.list). In case sources.list empty - You need to update it.

Comment: According to apt update output, the sources list has to be updated. Please refer to [link](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories) .