# How to fix: “zipalign: error while loading shared libraries: liblog.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory”

Tags: apt, kali-linux, dpkg, shared-library

[image]

The zipalign is installed but it is not working. I installed it from a .deb file by : "root@kali:~# sudo dpkg -i zipalign_21-4_amd64.deb" Please help

Comment: Why are no repositories configured? Did you remove or edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`, or files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`? `zipalign` is available [from the Kali repositories](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/android-platform-build), you should install it from there.

Comment: @StephenKitt No i didn't edited anything in the sources.list, but i can't install it directly, it says unable to find the package. Can you show or tell me the contents of the sources.list

Answer (score 1):

The fact that all your package lines (from `apt list`) end with “[installed,local]” means that you don’t have any configured repositories, so the first thing to do is to fix that, using the appropriate [Kali repository](https://www.kali.org/docs//general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/):

```
echo deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib > /etc/apt/sources.list
```

(Note that this will replace all your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.)

Then, update your repositories:

```
apt update
```

You’ll probably need to remove `zipalign` at this point, temporarily:

```
dpkg -r zipalign
```

But you’ll then be able to install the current version from the repository:

```
apt install zipalign
```

See also [What should be in the sources.list for Kali Rolling Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/370587/86440)